# iDRAC: Does racadm have some kind of "echo" command?

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac

I'm writing some scripts to automate the interaction with `racadm` sessions. Sometimes I need to show some info messages to the users, like `Will retry in 30 seconds.` For now I just use an unknown command like this:

```
$ ssh admin@idrac-ip-addr
racadm> ECHO "Will retry in 30 seconds."
ERROR: Invalid command specified.
racadm>
```

This works though it's a bit ugly. So I want to know if there's anything like an `echo` command or does it support comments (like the `#` char in shells).

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't.

If you are running a script this is functionality you would build into the sending side. For example, if you are on Linux on a remote device connecting to the iDRAC, you would use [iDRAC Tools for Linux](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=df1nd) and as part of your bash script you would have the echos. For example:

```
sysinfo=$(racadm -r SERVERIP -u root -p YOURPASS getsysinfo)
echo $sysinfo
```